# Hover effect applies to all anchor tags in the page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply hover effect to a particular list in the page, I use the following code. But it applies to all the anchor tags in the page.
My code is as follows:

```
        #menu-projects-menu li a:hover,li a:focus {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color:yellow !important;
}
```

The id of my  is "menu-projects-menu"
Can anyone help me with this.
Thank you

Comment: Post Your Question Properly, Mentioned particular list which you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```css
#menu-projects-menu li a:hover,
#menu-projects-menu li a:focus {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color:yellow !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you bro, this one works.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this:

```css
#menu-projects-menu li a:link {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color:red;
}

#menu-projects-menu li a:hover  {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color:yellow;
}

#menu-projects-menu li a:active  {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<ol id="menu-projects-menu">
  <li><a href="#coffee" target="_blank" >Coffee </a></li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Mango juice </li>
  <li><a href="#Milk" target="_blank"> Milk </a></li>
</ol>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply.